# Polylines outline construction / Drawing thick polylines

Tags: java, algorithm, graphics, libgdx, graphics2d

I'm facing a task where I have to draw polylines using polygons.
As an input parameters I have an array of points and thickness value. See picture below.
[image]

I have points that form black polyline and thickness e.g. 10px. Now I need to calculate points and construct a blue polyline to form a polygon and then render it.

There are some articles related to this:

- [Drawing Polylines by Tessellation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/226569/Drawing-polylines-by-tessellation)
- [An algorithm for polylines outline construction](http://www.cescg.org/CESCG99/SKrivograd/)
- [EFFICIENT RENDERING OF THICK POLYLINES](http://www.cis.usouthal.edu/~hain/general/Theses/Swaminadhan_thesis.pdf)

But I find them a bit complicated and difficult to understand.
Aren't there any existing libraries or more simple algorithms to implement this. No rounded joints are required. I'm using java and libGDX.

Comment: Can't you simply go like this: For every black point: First, create a pseudo-normal, which is the mean of the normals of the incident lines of the point. Second, normalize the pseudo-normal and multiply it by the thickness. Third, add it to the black point to obtain the corresponding blue point.

Comment: what is the relation of the blue line to the black one?

Comment: @gpasch I used colors just to show that array of black points is given and based on them and thickness I need to determine array of blue points to be able to form a polygon

Comment: ok how are the blue points defined: can you describe it in words? do we just shift the black line up? do we rotate? what? I cant just imagine the blue points there must be a mathematical description

Comment: @gpasch The blue points should be drawn above (line segments should be parallel to) the black ones. So that the thickness of polygon would be constant and the joints of segments would be drawn properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm is as follows:

```
for each line:
  find the parallel line upwards:
    find the perpendicular: has a slope m2 in approximate
    check which side is right (compare angles)
    find the two points of the parallel line by solving a small equation problem (A, B, C)
  if this line is the first one keep it (l1)
  else find the intersection with the previous line (l1, l2): this will give the next articulation point
```

The yellow line is the one you want; the red line is the general parallel line.
The articulation points are in green. You can print this bufferedimage in some component.

Notes: the width of the polygon cannot be fixed as you realize because at articulation points the distance will be larger. What is guaranteed is that the distance between line segments is constant.

```
int[] approximate(int[] p, int[] p2, double dr, int l) { // l is the distance, dr is 0 for the beginning of the segment and 1 for the end
          double d=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p[0]-p2[0], 2)+Math.pow(p[1]-p2[1], 2));
          double ix=p[0]+dr*(p2[0]-p[0]), iy=p[1]+dr*(p2[1]-p[1]);
          double x1=0, x2=0, y1=0, y2=0;
          if(p2[0]==p[0]) {
            x1=ix+l; x2=ix-l; y1=iy; y2=iy;
          }
          else {
          double m=1.0*(p2[1]-p[1])/(p2[0]-p[0]);
          if(Math.abs(m)==0) {
            x1=ix; x2=ix; y1=iy+l; y2=iy-l;
          }
          else {
            double m2=-1/m;
            double c=iy-m2*ix;
            double A=1+m2*m2, B=-2*(ix-m2*c+m2*iy), C=ix*ix+iy*iy+c*c-2*c*iy-l*l;
            x1=(-B+Math.sqrt(B*B-4*A*C))/(2*A); x2=(-B-Math.sqrt(B*B-4*A*C))/(2*A); y1=m2*x1+c; y2=m2*x2+c;
          }
          }
          int[] cp1={p2[0]-p[0], p2[1]-p[1]}, cp2={(int)x1-p[0], (int)y1-p[1]}, xy=new int[2];
          int cpp=compareAngles(cp1, cp2);
          if(cpp>0) { xy[0]=(int)x1; xy[1]=(int)y1; } else { xy[0]=(int)x2; xy[1]=(int)y2; }
          return xy;
  }

  void poly() {
    int[][] p={{100, 400}, {110, 440}, {250, 300}, {350, 400}, {300, 310}};
    BufferedImage bim=new BufferedImage(500, 500, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g=(Graphics2D)bim.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5f));
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    Line2D.Double l1=new Line2D.Double(), l2=new Line2D.Double();
    int[] currentp=new int[2], lastp=new int[2];
    for(int i=0; i<p.length-1; i++) {
      g.setColor(Color.black);
      g.drawLine(p[i][0], p[i][1], p[i+1][0], p[i+1][1]);
      int[] p1=approximate(p[i], p[i+1], 0, 10), p2=approximate(p[i], p[i+1], 1, 10);
      g.setColor(Color.red);
      g.drawLine(p1[0], p1[1], p2[0], p2[1]);
      if(i==0) { l1=new Line2D.Double(p1[0], p1[1], p2[0], p2[1]); currentp[0]=p1[0]; currentp[1]=p1[1]; }
      else {
        l2=new Line2D.Double(p1[0], p1[1], p2[0], p2[1]);
        int[] pi=intersectionPoint(l1, l2);
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillOval(pi[0], pi[1], 5, 5);
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.drawLine(currentp[0], currentp[1], pi[0], pi[1]);
        currentp[0]=pi[0]; currentp[1]=pi[1];
        l1.setLine(l2);
      }
      if(i==p.length-2) { lastp[0]=p2[0]; lastp[1]=p2[1]; }
    }
    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
    g.drawLine(currentp[0], currentp[1], lastp[0], lastp[1]);
  }

  public int[] intersectionPoint(Line2D.Double l1, Line2D.Double l2) {
    return intersectionPoint((int)l1.getX1(), (int)l1.getY1(), (int)l1.getX2(), (int)l1.getY2(), (int)l2.getX1(), (int)l2.getY1(), (int)l2.getX2(), (int)l2.getY2());
  }

  public int[] intersectionPoint(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3, int x4, int y4) {
    int[] xy={(int)(1.0*((x1*y2-y1*x2)*(x3-x4)-(x1-x2)*(x3*y4-y3*x4))/((x1-x2)*(y3-y4)-(y1-y2)*(x3-x4))),
                (int)(1.0*((x1*y2-y1*x2)*(y3-y4)-(y1-y2)*(x3*y4-y3*x4))/((x1-x2)*(y3-y4)-(y1-y2)*(x3-x4)))};
    return xy;
  }


  public int compareAngles(int[] a, int[] b) {
    int cp=a[0]*b[1]-a[1]*b[0];
    return -cp;
  }
```

Comment: Awesome! That is what I needed. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure why you want to implement some advanced graphics alghoritms in framework which first place duty is to render things easily :)

Libgdx has built-in [ShapeRenderer](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.html) that allows you to draw simple shapes. All you have to do is to calculate new vertices basing on `thickness` and pass them to the ShapeRenderer to draw circles and lines that connects these circles.

To make it super-easy you can even use

```
    rectLine(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, float width)
```

method that allows you to draw line of given thickness. So only what you need to do is to iterate over points and draw all lines like in this pseudo code:

```
    for point in points:
        if thereIsANextPoint():
            next = getNextPoint()

            sr.rectLine(point.x, point.y, next.x, next .y, thickness)
```

The nice description of how to use ShapeRenderer is included in [reference](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.html) I've attached above

---

I guess that there can be a little problem with joinings between points (because of different angles for example) I think that rendering circles above this joins will be good workarround :)

Comment: I can't use ShapeRenderer.rectLine() because of the problem with joints of line segments and because I need to color vertices with gradient and apply textures to it. So I decided to use a Mesh and now I'm searching for an algorithm to calculate those points to form a polygon.